# Check if not mouse over an element using jquery

Tags: jquery, mousemove, mouseleave

I have been trying to make my own tooltip that works great apart from if you go fast with the mouse and move out of the div the tooltip is still showing.

The issue with this is the tooltip is following the cursor so it is annoying if you are not over the element that it was intended for.

The issue looks like if you do it to fast then it does not fire the mouseleave function that hides the tooltip.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  "use strict";

  function tooltipHover() {
    $('.table-pointer, .ajax-table-pointer').mouseover(function() {

      //const year = $(this).attr('data-y');
     // const month = $(this).attr('data-m');
      //const qid = $(this).attr('data-q');

      //var invoiceFormData = {
      //  'type': 2,
      //  'year': year,
      //  'month': month,
      //  'qid': qid
      //};

      //$.ajax({
       // type: 'POST',
       // url: '/Applications/Controllers/Tracker/ajax.php',
       // data: invoiceFormData,
       // dataType: 'html',
       // encode: true
    //  }).done(function(data) {
       // $('.ubltool').html(data).show();
     // });
     //commented this out because I can not call through this
     
     $('.ubltool').html('tsteadasd').show();
    }).mouseleave(function() {
      $('.ubltool').hide();
    });
  }

  $('.table tr td.table-pointer, .table tr td.ajax-table-pointer').on('mousemove', function(e) {

    var newX = e.pageX - 200;
    var newY = e.pageY + 30;
    $('.ubltool').css({
      left: newX,
      top: newY
    });
  });
  tooltipHover();
});
```

```css
.table{width:80%;margin:200px 10%;}

.ubltool {
  position: fixed;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  top: 49%;
  left: 48.85%;
  padding: 10px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="table-pointer">Here</td>
      <td>Here</td>
      <td>Here</td>
      <td class="table-pointer">Here</td>
      <td class="table-pointer">Here</td>
      <td>Here</td>
      <td class="table-pointer">Here</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="table-pointer">Here</td>
      <td>Here</td>
      <td>Here</td>
      <td>Here</td>
      <td>Here</td>
      <td class="table-pointer">Here</td>
      <td>Here</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="table-pointer">Here</td>
      <td>Here</td>
      <td>Here</td>
      <td class="table-pointer">Here</td>
      <td>Here</td>
      <td>Here</td>
      <td class="table-pointer">Here</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Here</td>
      <td>Here</td>
      <td>Here</td>
      <td class="table-pointer">Here</td>
      <td class="table-pointer">Here</td>
      <td>Here</td>
      <td >Here</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Here</td>
      <td class="table-pointer">Here</td>
      <td>Here</td>
      <td>Here</td>
      <td>Here</td>
      <td>Here</td>
      <td class="table-pointer">Here</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="table-pointer">Here</td>
      <td>Here</td>
      <td>Here</td>
      <td>Here</td>
      <td>Here</td>
      <td>Here</td>
      <td class="table-pointer">Here</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<div class="ubltool"></div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Kindly update with relevant CSS and HTML

Comment: @mplungjan I have added the css which isn't what the question was regarding and that is why I did not think to add it to the code. The HTML is just a basic HTML table with some TD elements that have the classes that the jquery is being triggered by. The issue isn't the HTML or CSS, it is definitely the jquery side.

Comment: But we need the HTML to run the code!!! Why should we eyeball debug your code?

Comment: @Robert yes, but to help us help you having a reproducible problem in your question is good. [mcve]

Comment: You need to scroll down after clicking edit and "edit snippet" and remove the ajax - give us a [mcve] using dummy data

Comment: We do not see tabletool and not ubitool either - it could be some overlapping triggers mouseout. We have no idea

Comment: Use mouseenter and not mouseover

Comment: @minimal I have updated the code, sorry I mis-typed the code when I was typing it down quickly

Comment: Your code does not work - you need to change the AJAX to some dummy html

Comment: @mplungjan I have removed the ajax and just added a bunch of chars

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56540247/check-if-not-mouse-over-an-element-using-jquery/56544138?noredirect=1#comment99669851_56540247 - use mouseenter instead of mouseover - I deleted my answer so you can delete your question

Comment: @mplungjan so the issue is the fact that waiting for the ajax to load its content causes conflict.

But my question was never answered, I new the issue was it was not firing the mouseleave.

My question was how to check if the cursor is not over an element, rather than is over. Back in the old JS you could use is() but you can not do that for a number of years now.

Comment: @Robert $("element").is(someselector) should work

Comment: Problem is the code does not cancel the ajax call when it is hidden so it will fire the show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went down another route.

I am not saying this is the answer or the correct way but it works.

But I will post here for future reference just in case someone else down the line has a similar issue.

I changed the following code:

```
$('.table tr td.table-pointer, .table tr td.ajax-table-pointer').on('mousemove', function(e) {

    var newX = e.pageX - 200;
    var newY = e.pageY + 30;
    $('.ubltool').css({
      left: newX,
      top: newY
    });
  });
```

To

```
$('body').on('mousemove', function(e){

        var newX = e.pageX - 200;
        var newY = e.pageY + 30;

        $('.ubltool').css({

            left:  newX,
            top:   newY

        });

        if(e.target.classList.contains('table-pointer')){

            $('.ubltool').show();

        } else {

            $('.ubltool').hide();

        }

    });
```

I then basically removed the Mouseleave function and removed the show(); from $('.ubltool').html('tsteadasd').show();

That has corrected the issue I was having.

Answer (score 0):

I have already done something like this and its quit easy. 
Here is my script have a look

```js
(function ($) {
    $.toolTipIni = function () {

        function build() {
            // Get all span, input, li that have title
            var items = $("span[title]:not([title='']):visible,a[title]:not([title='']):visible,div[title]:not([title='']):visible,input[title]:not([title='']):visible,li[title]:not([title='']):visible");
            $(items).each(function () {
                var o = $(this);
                var title = o.attr("title");
                if (title && title != "" && !o.is(":hidden")) {
                    var offset = this.getBoundingClientRect();
                    o.attr("title", "");
                    o.addClass("tooltips");
                    var toolSpan = $("<span class='toolSpan'>" + title + "</span>");
                    toolSpan.css({
                        top: (offset.top + offset.height) + 10,
                        left: offset.left + (offset.width / 2)
                    });

                    o.append(toolSpan);
                    toolSpan.hide();
                    var timeOut = undefined;
                    o.mouseover(function (e) {
                        var offset = o[0].getBoundingClientRect();
                        clearTimeout(timeOut);
                        timeOut = setTimeout(function () {
                            toolSpan.css({
                                left: e.clientX,
                                top: e.clientY + 10
                            });
                            toolSpan.show();
                        }, 800); // wait before showing ths tooltip
                    }).mouseout(function () {
                        clearTimeout(timeOut);
                        toolSpan.hide();
                    });

                }
            });

            setTimeout(build, 100);
        }
        build();
    }
}(jQuery));

$(document).ready(function(){
//  simple start the tooltip
// you could modify it to your need 
$.toolTipIni();
});
```

```css
.tooltips {
    /*position: relative;*/
    /*display: inline;*/
}

    .tooltips > span.toolSpan {
        position: fixed;
        width: auto !important;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        background: #000000;
        height: auto !IMPORTANT;
        line-height: 30px;
        text-align: center;
        visibility: hidden;
        border-radius: 6px;
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-right: 10px;
        font-size: 12px !important;
        font-weight: normal !important;
    }

        .tooltips > span.toolSpan:after {
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 100%;
            left: 16%;
            margin-left: -8px;
            width: 0;
            height: 0;
            border-bottom: 8px solid #000000;
            border-right: 8px solid transparent;
            border-left: 8px solid transparent;
        }

    .tooltips:hover.tooltips > span.toolSpan {
        visibility: visible;
        opacity: 0.8;
        top: 30px;
        left: 50%;
        /*margin-left: -76px;*/
        z-index: 999;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span title="this is a test">hover here</span>
```

Comment: Yep i know, but there is things he did not think about. like the tooltip show exactly when the mouse hover over the text which dose not really work like a tooltip. So i presented him my own version that inc the problem he have with mouseeneter and leave and also the timeout solution

Comment: So you are basically saying use css and not jquery to hide the tooltip?

Comment: Im using Jq to create, show and hide the tooltip. and also cal the position where the tooltip is showing. the css is only to design the tooltip